# Subclass MKMapView and makes it mapview delegate while still allow other delegate

Tags: ios, objective-c, delegates, mkmapview, mapkit

I have a design problem. Here is what I want to do: I want to constraint `MKMapView` to a specific region, while making it an abstraction for the view controller which want to actually work with the map.

To constraint the map view I most likely want to use the delegate method `mapView:regionDidChangeAnimated:` and get notified of the changes and move the map back if the region is out of my pre-determined region. However, since I want to make it generic enough I don't want the code to be in view controller. I thought I might want to sub-class MKMapView instead.

If I do that I would have a subclass of `MKMapView` (say, a `ConstraintMapView` class) which is also the delegate of `MKMapView` and expose the methods to constraint the region to any user of the class. But then the user of the class (say a view controller) would also expect to be a delegate of `MKMapView`, so I would also want to forward all delegate messages to the view controller.

To do so I need a delegate property which points to the *real* delegate (the view controller), but in my `ConstriantMapView` if I have one does that mean I'm overriding the `MKMapView`'s setter and getter to the delegate and things get kind of complicated because inside `MKMapView` it could call `ConstraintMapView`'s methods and I would give it the view controller but I really want to give it `ConstraintMapView` instead.

1. Is there a way to make this work?
2. Is there a better pattern for the problem that spares the controller from the nitty-gritty of moving the view back to the constrainted region?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have done a similar proxying `MKMapViewDelegate` in this project; check it out:

https://github.com/mapbox/mbxmapkit

Comment: Oh Hi I posted on MapBox forum from time to time, too. In fact I'm currently trying to use the native sdk with MBTiles now that iOS7 makes it easy to load map onto it. So with MBXMapKit you're only overriding setDelegate in your MKMapView subclass but not overriding the getter? How do you make sure when MKMapView wants to send message to its delegate, it's not going to send directly to the real delegate and bypass your `MBXMapViewDelegate` altogether?

Comment: I think I start to get it. Awesome solution.

Comment: What's the difference between using NSProxy to stand in and using NSObject? As `forwardInvocation:` and `methodSignatureForSelector` seems to be there for NSObject as well?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to over right  an Existing class, you can use "The decorator design pattern". Here is the brief explanation.
 http://www.raywenderlich.com/46988/ios-design-patterns 
Hope It helps

Comment: Both delegation and category would run into the problem I described.